# NAT64 network sharing from Mac Mini issue

Tags: ipv6

I'm currently sharing IPv6 network from my Mac Mini for testing app before submit to Appstore.
Everything is working perfectly. But since last week, after a power outage no one can connect to my IPv6 network. I've tried to forget network then reconnect but after input password my iDevice auto jump to other network. I'm using iOS Console application for check my device log and see this lines:

> Sep 20 09:59:16 iPhone Preferences(AirPortSettings)[652] : -[APNetworksController _joinNetwork:isOtherNetwork:]: Moving new network to the top: >
>   Sep 20 09:59:22 iPhone wifid[41] : WiFi:[496033162.489797]: __WiFiLQAMgrSetCurrentNetwork: SSID: IPv6 BSSID: a8:86:dd:b4:34:5 RSSI: -35 Chan: 11 ApEnv: 0
>   Sep 20 09:59:22 iPhone mDNSResponder[97] :    Network Configuration Change     No IPv6 address TENTATIVE, will continue
>   Sep 20 09:59:22 iPhone wifid[41] : WiFi:[496033162.558781]: Failed to join(-3924 - 0xFFFFF0AC): IPv6
>   Sep 20 09:59:22 iPhone Preferences(MobileWiFi)[652] : WiFi:[496033162.563995]: __WiFiSecurityRemovePassword:[IPv6] Error result -25300
>   Sep 20 09:59:22 iPhone Preferences(AirPortSettings)[652] : -[APNetworksController updateCurrentNetworkUI]: Moving former current (IPv6) back to the main list
>       "@\134"CUTWiFiManagerSSID\134"" = IPv6;
>       "@\134"CUTWiFiManagerSSID\134"" = IPv6;

I don't know what is it. Try to ask Apple Support but they can't help. Does someone faced this issue like me? Please help!

Comment: try recreate NAT64 network on your mac mini?

Comment: @qin I tried. But it's not work.